# Who is Regina's father?

Tags: dark

In one of the final episodes of *Dark*, we see Claudia and Tronte talk about Regina, Tronte confessing that he wondered if he was her father, with Claudia telling him he's not.

The [familiy tree on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_(TV_series)#Complete_family_tree) lists Bernd Doppler as the father (although misspelled as *Bernard*). This seems plausible, but I don't recall seeing that mentioned in the series anywhere, just a scene that made it clear he did fancy her (at an age that was completely inappropriate).

Do we actually learn who Regina's father is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking this question, I came across [the official website](https://dark.netflix.io) for *Dark*, that lists Bernd Doppler as Regina's father, in all possible timelines.

Comment: There is also a photo of Regina, Claudia and Bernd at the end of the final episode, just before the dinner.